# xamarin form: Loading image to image control

Tags: android, ios, image, xamarin

How do i load an image file from iOS or Android using PCLStorage to an image control with ImageSource.

```
public string GetMediaFilePath(int orgId, string folderName, string filename)
    {
        var storage_root = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.Path;
        var rootFolderName = string.Format(ROOT_PREFIX, orgId);
        var path = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", storage_root, rootFolderName, filename);
        return path; }

<controls:CircleImage 
        Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Style="{StaticResource profileImageStyle}" 
          Source="{Binding Source}" 
          VerticalOptions="Center"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"> 
</controls:CircleImage>

public ImageSource Source 
        {
            get 
            {
                var file = new MediaLogic().GetMediaFilePath(Model.OrgId, MediaLogic.PROFILE_IMAGE_FOLDER, Model.ProfileImage);
                return "file:///"+file;
            }
        }
```

I have tried remove file:/// and use ImageSource.FromFile or FromUri but none of them show the image.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

PCLStorage has IFile.OpenAsync() which will return a stream.

```
Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.Read);
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

Comment: I am using getter property to bind to the Image Source property. Do I allow to do async in getter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bind to load your image source, you should use **Converter**.

Firstly create a Converter like:

```
public class ImageFileToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var path = (string)value;
        return ImageSource.FromFile(path);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in your XAML:

```
<controls:CircleImage 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Style="{StaticResource profileImageStyle}" 
        Source="{Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource ImageFileToImageSourceConverter}}" 
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"> 
</controls:CircleImage>
```

Also here is the dataSource class:

```
public class FileSource
{
    public string Source
    {
        get
        {
            var file = new MediaLogic().GetMediaFilePath(Model.OrgId, MediaLogic.PROFILE_IMAGE_FOLDER, Model.ProfileImage);
            return file;
        }
    }
}
```

At last do not forget set your `BindingContext` to this class:`MyStackLayout.BindingContext = new FileSource();`